# BSD sockets and timeouts in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sockets, unix

I setup a socket option like this:

```
struct timeval tv;
tv.tv_sec = 0;
tv.tv_usec = 0;
if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &tv, sizeof(tv)) == -1) {
    perror("setsockopt");
    exit(1);
}
```

When I do this the socket blocks forever on a recv call but when I set tv_usec to 1 the socket timesout as expected.  Is this expected behavior?  Any help in understanding this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the official [POSIX.1 manual page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_10):

> The default for this option is the value zero, which indicates that a receive operation will not time out.

So if you set the timeout to zero yourself it will be the same as the default which is no timeout.